# Is it a poor practise to add additional methods to an implementation not defined in the interface in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, interface, implementation, factory

I have an interface for verifying data from a database, and its implementations do different things with the lookup and check functions. Some of the implementations require additional functions in order to complete their task, is this a poor practise?

Comment: Are the additional methods public or private/protected?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your question is if it is OK for a class that implements an interface to have more methods than those actually defined in the interface?  The answer would be yes, that's perfectly fine, and quite normal in fact.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is not a poor practice as long as you don not expose those additional functions that go beyond what the interface defines; as in having them `protected` or `private`

Edit:

He had the tag `factory` in his question as well. So I assumed he is using the `factory method`. As such it would be bad that a given interface implementation to have more methods exposed that defined in the interface.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have additional `public` methods as well. With your current answer, it would mean that your class `Foo` that implements `Iterator` cannot have any public methods other than those defined in `Iterator`. That probably renders your class useless.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bad practice per se. What is important is if you can use the extending class using exactly same function calls as the parent class (as far as this Interface is concerned).

See: [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score 0):

As long as they respect the interface signature (that is, implement the interface methods according to their signature), I see no problem with the implementations adding additional methods.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a "service contract", where a class that implements the interface HAS to provide the functions described on the interface... that class can use different functions (or not) to provide that service, so, it's not a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

It is common to see classes implement an interface and additional methods. What is important is that you continue to obey the Single Responsibility Principle. That is, clients of your class will have some idea of the behaviour of your object based on the interface that it implements and you want to ensure that you do not violate their expectations.

Answer (score 0):

It is not poor practice if you use it correctly. Let me show an example. With these:

```
interface Foo {
   public function foo();
}

class Baz implements Foo {
   public function foo() {
      // implementation of Foo::foo()
   }

   public function baz() {
      // specific to Baz
   }
}
```

The following is poor practice:

```
function test(Foo $foo) {
    $foo->foo();
    $foo->baz();
}
test(new Baz);
```

In PHP, it works. In pre-compiled languages, it doesn't. It's because your argument `$foo` is of type `Foo`, which does not have a `baz` method. It would be a compile error:  the compiler checks against a argument of type `Foo`, and `Foo::baz` is an invalid reference. However, those do not exist in PHP, so as long as you pass your function a `Baz` object, it would work. But it opens the door to weird runtime errors.

The proper way would be to do:

```
function test(Baz $foo) {
    $foo->foo();
    $foo->baz();
}
test(new Baz);
```